# Making an asynchronous timer: Efficiency of many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently thinking about a very simple asynchronous timer class. It's basically a wrapper for a std::thread that creates a new (non-blocking) thread (for each timer one thread). The new thread then waits for the specified amount and calls a callback.
Pseudocode:

```
class AsyncTimer
{
    void threadFunc(...)
    {
        sleep_thread(seconds);
        CallbacKFunction();
    }

    std::thread _thread;

    AsyncTimer(int seconds, CallbackFunction)
    {
        // Create thread (threadFunc) that waits and then calls CallbackFunction
        _thread = std::thread(threadFunc);
        _thread.StartNonBlocking();
    }
};
```

Is this concept still a good approach/efficient if I have 50 or more running timers (and therefore threads)?

Or should I make a "Timers-Container" containing all Timers (which than don't have an own thread), which only creates one thread in which all timers will be updated sequentially (wait specified time by measuring elapsed, then call CallbackFunc)?

I would expect that 50 or so threads could be a problem, even if they do nothing most of the time.

Note: This is currently only a "thought problem" I want to test out by implementing. So other methods of implementing many asynchronous timers are welcome. Some day I will move to a Job / Dispatch queue system so this should take cark of the timer problem in the future.

Comment: I can't see a reason why 50 threads would be an issue when there are usually thousands on the average system. The sleep timer does not consume any resources at idle so it's fine, but you might run into performance issues when they wake up

Comment: It is very inefficient. Use one thread, a max heap for queueing timers and a signal to wake up thread for updating the closest sleep time if the top of a max heap changed from outside.

Comment: The only reason you might want to use more than one thread would be if you need your timeout-callbacks to run in parallel with each other rather than sequentially (and even then you could use a thread pool, so that that the number of threads is kept down to a reasonable/finite level, e.g. to no more than the number of cores in the computer)

Comment: Are you aware that sleep may be late? The time point (or delay) is the earliest time the OS may wake up your thread but if it does, there might be other threads already queued for execution. Additionally, the accuracy of `sleep()` may depend on the task slot times of the OS scheduler. On Windows, I noticed in the past that I got a resolution of round about 16 ms which was too slow for my purposes. I had to tweak the scheduler (with some multimedia lib. function) to get it down to (roundabout) 1 ms.